# Publishing linked dynamic components

Tags: 2013-sp1, templating, si4t

We have following case to solve: When a Page is published, which contains a component that references certain Multimedia components. Those mm components need to be published dynamically.

The reason for this is because there is extra metadata on those mm components that needs to be indexed by our Solr instance. The dynamic templates generate those metadata for us.

Kr,

Thomas

Comment: Is there a question there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a custom resolver; much like as described in this article: http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/a-custom-resolver-in-practice

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can achieve this via templating, no need for custom resolver. You can add additional dwt in your page template in which you will have RenderComponentPresentation() function for your metadata component with one or more defined templates. After that you can have your standard dwt for page that will generate your output. 
With this approach you always have your metadata component as CP in your package so you ensure that its always published when page is published (because its in package, it will get published also). Also, since you have later your second dwt, it will not be shown on page in any form.

We used this approach every time when we needed to publish one component when some other is published.